# Product of 2 Sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm in a discrete mathematics course wherein we're discussing set theory, and I'm asked to take the product of $2$ sets, but the notes I took aren't very clear, so I was hoping that someone here would come to the rescue. I have the question:
$\{a,b,c\}\times\{1,2\}$
I know that for that I need to take an element of each set, but they don't have the same number of elements and I don't really know what to do because of that.

Comment: {a,b,c} X {1,2}

Comment: The Cartesian product $X \times Y$ consists of all ordered pairs of the form $(x, y)$ where $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$, so just list all possible $x$ and all possible $y$ and you should get the result.

Comment: They don't need to have the same size. Draw up a multiplication table with the elements of the first set defining the rows and the elements of the second set defining the columns. You'll find that you end up with $3\times 2= 6$ cells, each of which contains an ordered pair where the first entry is an element of the first set and the second entry is an element of the second set, such as the ordered pairs  $(a,1)$ and $(a,2)$.

Answer (score 3):

The number of elements in the set doesn't matter. We define
$$
X \times Y := \{ (x,y) \mid x \in X, y \in Y \}
$$
i.e. $X \times Y$ is every possible pairing of elements where the first in the pair $x$ comes from the first set $X$, and the second in the pair $y$ comes from the second set $Y$.

For example,
$$
\{1,2\} \times \{3,4,5\} = \Big\{ (1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(2,3),(2,4),(2,5) \Big\}
$$

Comment: Thanks, that really helps. Seeing one worked out really helped. Now I can do the other 3 set product problems on my homework!